# How to embed Electron in a Windows window with a HWND

Tags: windows, electron

Having the HWND of window in Microsoft Windows, how can I start a BrowserWindow embedded in it effectively embedding my app?

I'm writing a screen saver for Windows and for configuration and preview I get passed the HWND of the parent window to embed my program in it.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily insert your processes window in another processes window in any meaningful way without the cooperation of the other application.  Perhaps you should describe what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Alex K: I have the cooperation of the other process. I'm writing a Screensaver and your program gets called with the HWND so you can embed it in the preview section of the settings.

Comment: @pupeno Did you ever solve this? I have the same challenge.